# right-click on a d3.js element: how to prevent browser context menu to appear

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some d3.js element plotted, eg:

```
 // draw rectangle 
  svg.selectAll(".rect").append("rect")
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("height", 5)
        .attr("width", 5)
        .on("contextmenu", function (d, i) {  
    // react on right-clicking
 });
```

and it works fine but also opens browser's context menu. How I can prevent that from happening?

Comment: Out of courtesy, you should accept an answer if it solves your problem, like Brian's answer...

Comment: Thank fir the reminder!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Add `d3.event.preventDefault();` to your function.

```
 // draw rectangle 
  svg.selectAll(".rect").append("rect")
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("height", 5)
        .attr("width", 5)
        .on("contextmenu", function (d, i) {
            d3.event.preventDefault();
           // react on right-clicking
        });
```

Comment: This code works for me. If I was the OP i would accept this answer.

Answer (score -3):

I understood and giving below code for you, check it and ask if you need any thing more...

```
// draw rectangle 
  svg.selectAll(".rect").append("rect")
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("height", 5)
        .attr("width", 5)
        .on("contextmenu", function (d, i) {
            d3.event.preventDefault();
           // react on right-clicking
        });
```